# Android: onSensorChanged() not called despite attaching listener

Tags: java, android, android-sensors

Couldn't find a solution from the existing posts. I'm trying to build a step counter using Android's built in TYPE_STEP_COUNTER sensor but the onSensorChange() method doesn't get called! In the below code, for example, "Outside *stepcount*" is never printed to the Logcat.

```
public class StepFragment extends Fragment implements SensorEventListener {

private int step_count = 0;
TextView stepCountText;
private Sensor mStepSensor;
private SensorManager mSensorManager;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stepfragment, container, false);
    stepCountText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.stepcounttext);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getActivity().getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mStepSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
}


    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Outside" + step_count);
        if (event.values[0] == 1.0f) {
            step_count++;
            System.out.println(step_count);
        }
        stepCountText.setText(Integer.toString(step_count));
    }

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mStepSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    if(mStepSensor != null)
    {
        System.out.println("Sensor step counter present");
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    System.out.println("Fragment Paused");
}
}
```

I do get "Sensor step counter present" in my Logcat which proves that my device indeed has the step_counter sensor. I'd be very grateful for some help!